# Change substrings of NSString to bold

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsattributedstring

I have an `NSString`, that contains tags `[strong][\strong]`. Inside this tags, this words must be **bold** to be shown in a `UITextView` and then delete all the container tags once words are formatted,and I can't use an `UIWebView`. I think I must use `attributedString`s, but I'm not sure how can I achieve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `UITextView` you can use advanced `UILabel` like [OHAttributedLabel](https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHAttributedLabel) or [CoreTextAttributedLabel](https://github.com/umerh/CoreTextAttributedLabel). Download the sample, its good & clean. You can change colors, fonts, sizes, underline, and almost everything for parts of a string.

Answer (score 1):

**For iOS 6.0**

Attributed strings will help you!

```
NSString* string = @"[strong]yourString[/strong]";
string = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"[strong]" withString:@""]
string = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"[\strong]" withString:@""];
UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:30.0f];
NSMutableAttributedString * attrString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:string];
[attrString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:fontName range:NSMakeRange(0, _stringLength)];
```

Make sure to set the label text to attributed.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
if([[yourString substringToIndex:8] isEqual:@"[strong]")
{
NSString *newString = [yourString substringFromIndex:8];
NSString *newerString = [newString substringToIndex:[newString length]-9];

//Insert to label and change label format to bold.

}
```